# Sklearn: MaxAbsScaler mandatory when your dataframe has a lot of dummy variables?

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization

I have a dataset with the following variables:

```
price (numerical, min 350, max 25400)
model_age_days (numerical, min 423,  max 3405)
factor_1 (dummy)
factor_2 (dummy)
factor_3 (dummy)
(...)
factor_58 (dummy)
```

So the model has 60 columns, 58 age of which are One Hot Encoded dummy variables (created using pandas its `get_dummies` feature). So for each row, most columns will have a value of `0`

I am training a classifier to predict the factor (but will likely perform other types of analysis later) , using a 'One vs the Rest' approach for each factor and am now trying to decide how to preprocess the data.

My question is as follows:

Am I correct in assuming that this dataset could be considered sparse and that, following the Sklearn documentation the `MaxAbsScaler` is thus almost mandatory?

```
MaxAbsScaler and maxabs_scale were specifically designed for
scaling sparse data, and are the recommended way to go about this.
```

I'm asking this since I would like to create a 2d graph (using PCA) later, but the tutorials / documentation seem to suggest that the `StandardScaler` is preferred for PCA.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data. For some algorithms it won't matter (random forest) for some it will (lasso).

Comment: Thanks for you response! I am I correct in understanding that, for the algorithms that require standardisation (lets say, SVM) a MaxAbsScaler would be the way to go here?